# Extract text between two strings if a substring exists between the two strings using Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file and want to extract text between two strings if a substring exists between those two strings. There may be multiple such instances in the text file. For example,

**Example text file (text_data)**:

```
ghsauaigyssts twh
 
ghguy  hja  StartString I want this text (1) if substring 1 lies in between the two strings EndString bhghk [jhbn] xxzh StartString I want this text (2) as a different variable if substring 2 lies in between the two strings EndString ghjyjgu
```

**Output:**

first_variable = I want this text (1) if substring 1 lies in between the two strings

second_variable = I want this text (2) as a different variable if substring 2 lies in between the two strings

**I tried extracting the first variable as:**

```py
target1 = 'StartString'

target2 = 'substring 1'

target3 = 'EndString'

pat1 = '{}(.+?){}(.+?){}'.format(target1,target2,target3)

pattern = re.compile(pat1, flags=re.DOTALL)

first_variable = pattern.findall(text_data)
```

Can anyone help me to understand what is wrong/ provide me a solution for this? Thanks

Comment: This looks like a logical issue, don't you mean to use `pat1 = '{}(.+?){}(.+?){}'.format(target1,target3,target2)`? However, this is a wrong pattern, you need `pat1 = '{0}((?:(?!{0}).)+?){1}(.+?){2}'.format(target1,target3,target2)`

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question to correct it. The solution you provided doesn't work as well. I am trying to understand it though. Do you recommend any study material to learn python Regex?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/mYKuXh, what does not work?

Comment: 'substring 1' is missing from the output text. I modified it to work with my actual text file with 900K lines in it, but it does not work. I think I am doing something wrong which I need to figure out

Comment: output looks like this:    [(' I want this text (1) if ', ' lies in between the two strings ')]

Comment: Try `pat1 = '{0}\s*((?:(?!{0}).)*?{1}.*?)\s*{2}'.format(target1,target2,target3)`, see https://ideone.com/fX4zhK

Comment: Thank you. This works with the question's example. I should be able to modify it to get it worked for my actual text file. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the code using

```
pat1 = '{0}\s*((?:(?!{0}).)*?{1}.*?)\s*{2}'.format(target1,target2,target3)
```

The pattern (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/IxjGBF/1)) is

```
StartString\s*((?:(?!StartString).)*?substring 1.*?)\s*EndString
```

**Details**

- `StartString` - left-hand delimiter
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `((?:(?!StartString).)*?substring 1.*?)` - Group 1:

  - `(?:(?!StartString).)*?` - any char, 0 or more but as few as possible, that does not start with the left-hand delimiter
  - `substring 1` - third string
  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `\s*EndString` - 0+ whitespaces and the right-hand delimiter.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/fX4zhK):

```
import re
text_data='ghsauaigyssts twh\n\nghguy  hja  StartString I want this text (1) if substring 1 lies in between the two strings EndString bhghk [jhbn] xxzh StartString I want this text (2) as a different variable if substring 2 lies in between the two strings EndString ghjyjgu'
target1 = 'StartString'
target2 = 'substring 1'
target3 = 'EndString'
pat1 = '{0}\s*((?:(?!{0}).)*?{1}.*?)\s*{2}'.format(target1,target2,target3)
pattern = re.compile(pat1, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(pattern.findall(text_data))
# => ['I want this text (1) if substring 1 lies in between the two strings']
```